# tensorflow prediction contains all zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently did the mnist tensorflow tutorial and wanted to try change it a bit. In this example I am trying to get an input of a 28*28*3 (3 for r,g,b) and give back the exact same output. For ease I am just doing pure white in and out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tensorflow as tf

input_layer_size = 2352 # number of pixels * number of color channels (rgb)

white = [255] * input_layer_size # white is a square of white pixels
white = [white]

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_layer_size])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_layer_size])

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_layer_size,input_layer_size], stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_layer_size], stddev=0.1))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y, 1e-10, 1.0)), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

for i in range(100):
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: white, y_: white})

feed_dict = {x:white}
classification = sess.run(y, feed_dict)
print ("Output:", classification[0])
```

for some reason the output of this is `[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]`. Why is it not the expected result (`[ 255., 255., ... ]`)?

I've tried the exact same code with the mnist data and it works fine, giving me 10 output channels with reasonable results in each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code it seems that you try to learn a linear transformation from x to y, where both x and y are (row) vectors representing two images: y = x * W + b. This is a regression problem. The solution would be W - identity matrix, and b is a zero vector. The code below solves this problem by minimizing |y - (x * W + b)|:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()

input_layer_size = 2352 # number of pixels * number of color channels (rgb)

white = [255] * input_layer_size # white is a square of white pixels
white = [white]

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_layer_size])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_layer_size])

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_layer_size,input_layer_size], stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_layer_size], stddev=0.1))

y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y - y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(1000):
  loss_, _ = sess.run([loss, train_step], feed_dict={x: white, y_: white})

print loss_

feed_dict = {x:white}
classification = sess.run(y, feed_dict)
print ("Output:", classification[0])
```

When you tried the same code with the mnist data, it worked because y is different: it's a one-hot encoding of the target digit, i.e. for 0 it would be 1, 0, 0, 0, ...; for 1 it would be 0, 1, 0, 0, ...; for 2 - 0, 0, 1, ... and so on.

Comment: Please ignore my accident comment above. Several things were wrong: y was clipped into (1e-10, 1) range, while it should be about 255 to minimize loss, the loss itself (cross entropy of softmax) is for a multiclass classification problem but not for a regression problem.

Comment: I see, the main problem is using the wrong loss, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that works really well. Could you please explain for me the difference between a linear transformation and a regression, and why the linear transformation wouldn't work here?

Comment: The code I suggested finds the parameters of the linear transformation (matrix W and vector b) by solving a regression problem. You can find more details about regression problem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis